# Existence of probability density of a functional of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, density-function, stopping-times, characteristic-functions

This is a proof verification question. The claim that I want to prove is as follows.

> > Let $(B,W)$ be two dimensional Brownian motion. Define the stopping time $\sigma_{n}$ as
> >     $$\sigma_n = \inf\left\{t > \frac{1}{n}: B_t = 0\right\}$$
> >     Then, $W_{\sigma_n}$ has a probability density.

My proof: $\sigma_{n}$ and $W$ are independent. Therefore, I can write
$$E\left[e^{i\theta W_{\sigma_n}}\right] = E\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2\sigma_{n}}\right]$$
for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Next, I want to employ the Fourier inversion theorem.
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}E\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2\sigma_{n}}\right]\,d\theta &= E\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2\sigma_{n}}\,d\theta \right]\\
&\leq E\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2n}\theta^2}\,d\theta \right]
\end{align}
In going from the first row to the second I made use of the fact that $\sigma_n \geq \frac{1}{n}$. Since the last expression is finite, the characteristic function of $W_{\sigma_n}$ is integrable. Hence, it possesses a density.

Is this proof correct? If not, how can I correct it?